# Python Defining Lists in Lists

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am trying to define a table colors which contains various other tables containing tuples which represent colors.

```
title_label = [
text = (236, 218, 51),
background = (125, 142, 246)
],
start_button = [
text = (32, 40, 145),
background = (236, 235, 136),
pressed = (44, 51, 112)
],
quit_button = [
text = (166, 21, 13),
background = (48, 61, 188),
pressed = (31, 40, 129)
]
```

However, this gives an invalid syntax error. Why is that?

Comment: Can you give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) about what you want to do?

Comment: Lists can't have labels like that.  Have you read [the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/tutorial) to familiarize yourself with basic Python data structures?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lists don't take name-value pairs. You probably want dictionaries here instead:

```
definitions = {
    'title_label': {
        'text': (236, 218, 51),
        'background': (125, 142, 246)
    },
    'start_button': {
        'text': (32, 40, 145),
        'background': (236, 235, 136),
        'pressed': (44, 51, 112)
    },
    'quit_button': {
        'text': (166, 21, 13),
        'background': (48, 61, 188),
        'pressed': (31, 40, 129)
    }
}
```

I'm not sure where you found your syntax, but it is not valid Python. Python lists, using `[...]` square brackets, can only take a sequence of individual Python expressions:

```
some_list = ['one object', {'dictionary': 'value'}, ['another', 'list']]
```

See the [*Data structures* section](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) of the Python tutorial.